# Hypersonic flow in Fluent

Tags: simulation, ansys-fluent

I am working in my graduating project about the hypersonic flow, particularly the properties of the air behind a strong shock wave, I try to do a simulation for that process in Fluent but I don't know exactly if that it's possible in Fluent. Anyone who have an idea how to do that?

Answer (score 3):

i wouldn't call this an answer yet - i assume the question you actually want to ask will require you to specify a lot more details.  is fluent capable of simulating hypersonic flow?  yes.  i'm sure you can find better literature, but [comparisons](http://enu.kz/repository/2010/AIAA-2010-7184.pdf) have been done, so maybe that will be useful to you if you have more options than fluent.

personally, i'd advise you pay attention to the type of grid you plan to use, but i don't know what your geometry is like.  is it symmetric in any way?  blunt or sharp geometry/what kind of shock do you expect?  what metric are you most closely tracking?  something like peak magnitude of surface heating, location, or both?  what do you plan to do with chemical nonequilibrium?  'how' to do it depends on a lot of things; the list goes on and on...

**EDIT:**
i assume this is an academic exercise, so i'm guessing this problem is going to be in translational/rotational equilibrium and vibrational nonequilibrium...and that you understand you'll see some differences between your finite difference method and fluent's cell centered finite volume method.  i don't have specific experience with your zeldovitch chemical model (zel'dovich? as in 1d znd detonation model?), more so with models by kang & dunn or park.  at any rate, can you ask something more specific than 'how do you set up a hypersonic flow solution in fluent'?

Comment: @SamirOuchene i only added a bit because this community is more built around answering targeted questions that demonstrate research has been done, as opposed to broad, opened ended tutorials.  i think you'll have more success getting answers here if you ask specific questions.  if this is your first time using a package like fluent, you might be surprised how many knobs there are for you to dial-an-answer.